# How to resolve 404 Error for an AJAX call in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am getting a 404 Error for an AJAX call in Django

Here's my code:
jQuery Script:

```
$('#cluster-id').change( function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax_demo/',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function( jqXHR, textStatus ){
                console.log("complete " + textStatus);
            },
            success: function( data, jqXHR, textStatus ){
                console.log("success " + data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            
                console.log("error: " + errorThrown );
            }
        });
```

I am trying to get the data( in json ) form this function:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def ajax_demo( request ):
    cluster = request.GET.get('cluster', None)
    data = {
        'name' : 'abc'
    }
return JsonResponse(data)
```

I have set the url correctly too:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url( r'^$', views.main_page_demo, name = 'main_page_demo' ),
    url( r'^demo/', views.ajax_demo, name = 'ajax_demo'),
        
    ]
```

I am new to AJAX and jQuery and i don't know what's the issue.

root url

```
urlpatterns =[
    
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include( 'app.urls', namespace = "mainPage")),
```

Comment: It should be `url: '/demo/',` not `url: '/ajax_demo/',`. You must enter there a url, not a url name (`ajax_demo`).

Comment: @nik_m  Made the changes, still the same issue.

Comment: @nik_m added the root url in the question

Comment: You realize that you *do not send* any data via the Ajax call. Along with the `dataType: 'json',` key-value pair, there should also be a `data: {key: value, otherKey: otherValue, ...}`. Also, put a `$` like this here: `r'^demo/$', ....`.

Comment: @nik_m, i Tried this and still got the same error.   data =  {'name' : 'abc' }
    return JsonResponse( {'data' : data})

Comment: @nik_m, and made the changes in the urls.py as well, still getting the error

Comment: No! That's not what I meant. Please, read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for how you should do it! `data: {key: value, otherKey: otherValue, ...}` should be placed inside the the `$.ajax({...});` and not inside your django view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several obvious errors here.

Firstly, you are posting to `/ajax_demo/`, but you don't have that as a URL; only `/demo/`. You did either change the URL pattern or the URL you are posting to.

Secondly, you have included the app patterns wrongly; to must not use a terminal `$` with include. It should be:

```
url(r'^$', include( 'app.urls', namespace = "mainPage")),
```

Thirdly, you​ are not including any data with your request. You need a `data` key:

```
   $.ajax({
            url: '/demo/',
            type: 'get',
            data: {"cluster": "value"}
            ...
```